# Zend_Di (Zend 2.0 beta) and Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: php, dependency-injection, namespaces, zend-framework

I was wondering if any one had any kind of success integrating a Zend Framework 2.0 beta in a Zend Framework 1.11 project.

I am currently building a project using ZF 1.11. I don't want to use ZF 2.0 yet since they say on the [developpers blog](http://devzone.zend.com/1935/zend-framework-200beta1-released/) that backward compatibility isn't guaranteed. The project developpement will span over a few months and I don't want to fix a lot of stuff when I update to the newest release (which will resolve bugs and vulnerabilities).

Is there a quick tutorial, or did anybody include a Zend Framework 2.0 module (using PHP namespaces) in a "vintage" Zend Framework release using includes?

Comment: Not guaranteed to be backwards compatible? It's guaranteed to not be backwards compatible.

Comment: BC between beta 2.0 and beta 2.1, that's why I'm not jumping in ZF2 yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative possibility, if what you want is to introduce Dependency Injection in your ZF 1.11 project, is to use the [Symfony DI component](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/). I worked fine for me.

There are some web resources about the details, most notably this one: http://losohome.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/integrating-symfony-dependency-injection-service-container-with-zend-framework/

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now have to setup my configs properly :D

Answer (score 0):

My advice at this stage is to develop your project with ZF 1.11. 2 will not be backwards compatible with ZF ZF 1.11, but there is talk of some tools / tutorials that will help to update, but I am very skeptical about it!